# Add transition in onmouseover and onmouseout using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am still new to this. how do i add transition from changing picture1 to picture2 while still using a  tag? can i also add a third image to the script so that when you hover on the picture, it shows you three pictures instead of two? here is my code

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src = "picture1.jpg" onmouseover="rollover(this)" onmouseout="mouseaway(this)">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function rollover(my_image)
    {my_image.src = 'picture2.jpg';}
    function mouseaway(my_image)
    {my_image.src = "picture1.jpg";}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: The best way I found to achieve this is using an `img` element per image and than switching between the images with javascript by changing the  CSS style `opacity` to `0` (or `1`). On the CSS layer I set the style to animate the `img` elements I want by using `transition: opacity 0.25s`. The elements will need to be positioned on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works..

```js
function rollover(my_image){
  my_image.style.width = "200px";
  my_image.style.transition = "width 2s, height 4s";
  my_image.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/';
}


function mouseaway(my_image){
  
     my_image.style.width = "50px";
     // my_image.style.opacity = "0.5";
      my_image.src = "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/";
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <img src = "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" onmouseover="rollover(this)" onmouseout="mouseaway(this)">
</body>

</html>
```